# Как сделать проверку на int, если число отправляется в виде str?

Tags: python

Есть тг бот и список, который создается из сообщений пользователя. В данном случае из цифр. Проблема в том, что любое сообщение получается в виде строки. То есть сообщение 1000 будет равно str(1000) или '1000'. Необходимо сделать проверку, является ли сообщение числом. И если это число, то добавить в список. Я сделал так:

```
    if int(message.text) % 1 == 0:
        messages.append(message.text)
```

Но в таком случае выходит ошибка, если я пробую сделать другое условие, например:

```
    elif message.text == 're':
        messages.append(message.text)
```

Может есть другой способ проверить является ли сообщение числом? Без преобразования в int прямо в условии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У строки есть встроенные методы для таких проверок:

```py
message.text.isdigit()
```

Результат:

```py
message.text = '1234'
print(message.text.isdigit())
# True
```

```py
message.text = '1234qwe'
print(message.text.isdigit())
# False
```

Однако надо учесть, что числа с плавающей точкой эту проверку проходить не будут:

```py
message.text = '12.56'
print(message.text.isdigit())
# False
```

Поэтому стоит поискать другой метод проверки или написать что-то вроде этого:

```py
def is_number(str):
    try:
        float(str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

```py
message.text = '12.56'
print(is_number(message.text))
# True
```

Comment: блин, как же всё просто. Просидел час с этим) Спасибо!

Comment: @ProTask Вообще, эту информацию можно было найти по первой ссылке по запросу в гугле "Python проверить является ли строка числом"  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение? :)

Comment: Правильно ввести запрос - уже половина решения проблемы. Но всё, что я находил, был ответ 12-ти летней давности на этом форуме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501382/checking-whether-a-variable-is-an-integer-or-not

Comment: Да, отмечу как решение